# Complex materials are not baked

Tags: texturing, materials

Hello/ Help me figure it out. Never had any problems with baking in Substance Painter, but decided to sing in a blender and not in any way. Normal, AO and Roughness are Baked without problems, but Diffuse does not want to. It just gives a black texture. There is a scan. What is the error? I tried on the same model with a simpler material, everything works. and then I change to another, more complex material and everything is baked black square) in the photo, the material that is not baked... I can't figure out what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect your problems come from the use of the Fresnel node, which is view dependent, so baking can't really handle it.  It's used to mix between diffuse and emission, and any emission, for purposes of a diffuse color bake, comes out as black.  But I'll tell you straight off, your diffuse color, if you ignore the view-dependent stuff, is the single solid color of blue you have in your shader's Base Color field.

Comment: no, it didn't help... I tried to disable Fresnel node and emission the result was the same. but then it turned out that this is the Metalic controller. without it, everything is baked. thank you!

Comment: @ EVA-Stud Oh yeah, I missed that metallic value.  Metallic has no diffuse, it's all specular.

Comment: And it turns out that you can't upload all the maps here as it is done in Substance Painter? I did not find a metal map how to bake, base color is also not the same. Is there any functionality in the blender that would bake all the cards similar to Substance Painter?